# OperationalError: unable to open database file: sqlalchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, ubuntu, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating an flask api on ubuntu server. My code runs on native machine (without apache)but why deploying it I get OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file.

**Code:**

home.py

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify, request
from models import UsersLoginInfo,Base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlalchemy.pool

sqlite = sqlalchemy.pool.manage(sqlite3, poolclass=sqlalchemy.pool.SingletonThreadPool)
engine = sqlite.create_engine('sqlite:///database/userslogininfo.db')

Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login',methods=['POST'])
def home():
    data_rec = {'username' : request.json['username'], 'password' : request.json['password']}
    users = [i.serialize['username'] for i in session.query(UsersLoginInfo).all()]
    passwords = [i.serialize['password'] for i in session.query(UsersLoginInfo).all()]
    login=False
    try:
        user_index=users.index(unicode(data_rec['username']))
        password_from_db=passwords[user_index]
        if password_from_db==data_rec['password']:
            login=True
            msg=None
        else:
            msg="Wrong password entered."
    except ValueError:
        msg="There is no user with that username, please create an account."
    return jsonify({'login' : login ,"msg": msg})

@app.route('/create',methods=['POST'])
def create():
    data_rec = {'username' : request.json['username'], 'password' : request.json['password']}
    users = [i.serialize['username'] for i in session.query(UsersLoginInfo).all()]
    if data_rec['username'] in users: #check account exists
        account_exists=True
        msg="An account with that username already exists, please choose another username."
    else:
        account_exists=False
        id=len(users)
        user = UsersLoginInfo(username = unicode(data_rec['username']), password = unicode(data_rec['password']), id = id)
        session.add(user)
        session.commit()
        msg="Your account has been created. Please login with it."
    return jsonify({'account_exists' : account_exists ,"msg": msg})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import Column,Integer,String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()
class UsersLoginInfo(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'userslogininfo'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
  username = Column(String)
  password = Column(String)

  #Add a property decorator to serialize information from this database
  @property
  def serialize(self):
    return {
      'username': self.username,
      'password': self.password,
      }

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database/userslogininfo.db')


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

FlaskApps.wsgi

```
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApps/notepad_app/")
print "hello"
# home points to the home.py file
from home import app as application
application.secret_key = "somesecretses212sionkey"
```

**Error(from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`):**

http://pastebin.com/vdAVrFFN

**Debugging:**
 The user that runs apache is `www-data`.

```
ubuntu@ip-171-31-38-0:/var/www/FlaskApps$ ls
FlaskApps.wsgi  notepad_app
ubuntu@ip-171-31-38-0:/var/www/FlaskApps$ tree
.
├── FlaskApps.wsgi
└── notepad_app
    ├── clean_log.sh
    ├── database
    ├── home.py
    ├── home.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── print_log.sh
    ├── README.md
    └── restart.sh

2 directories, 9 files
ubuntu@ip-171-31-38-0:/var/www/FlaskApps$
```

The database has to be created in the database folder above.

```
ubuntu@ip-171-31-38-0:/var/www/FlaskApps/notepad_app$ ls -ld database/
drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 13 21:31 database/
```

When I run home.py from python interpreter it works perfectly and creates a .db in database folder

```
ubuntu@ip-171-31-38-0:/var/www/FlaskApps/notepad_app$ python home.py
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 312-927-730
ubuntu@ip-171-31-38-0:/var/www/FlaskApps/notepad_app$ ls database/
userslogininfo.db
```

Comment: And why isn't your question a duplicate of the linked ones?

Comment: @CL. I tried solutions from those questions, but it didn't work. Therefore, asked. My code employs the threads. Sry for mentioning explicitly.

Comment: What do you think the absolute path of the `userslogininfo.db` is? Are you sure? Do you have write permissions to that file? If the file doesn't exist, do you have permissions to create the file in that directory?

Comment: Same folder, works on my local machine. Who is executing the file, it is in `/var/www`.

Comment: What if you try to print where the working directory is? Put `print os.getcwd()` in your module.

Comment: @univerio where is the output redirect?

Comment: It depends on how you're integrating Python with Apache. Check the docs.

Comment: A guess: your apache user doesn't have permissions to write to the directory you're trying to use.  You could add a lot more debugging information to help solve this - for instance when you say it works on the local machine, do you mean under apache on the local machine or using the dev server?  You give two SO questions as "references", but don't explain their relevance - why don't they solve your problem (particularly the second).  Please add this info into the question (not in comments, where it can get lost).

Comment: @JRichardSnape Thanks for the suggestion. Please check the question now. I am still not able to fix it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After discussion with the poster on [/dev/chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat), he informed me that specifying an absolute path for the location of the SQLite database fixed the problem.

Comment: Thanks! Also, special thanks to @Antti Haapala and @J Richard Snape.